# Show link when all input fields filled

Tags: jquery

I trying to use jquery to check a form with dynamically created formfields to assure that all input fields have been filled prior to submission. I would like to hide submit link until all the fields are filled. This is what I have so far.

```
$( 'form#form_id' ).change(function(e) {
 $(":input").each(function() {
    if($(this).val() === ""){
        $("#showlink").hide();
      }else{
        $("#showlink").show();
      }
    });
});
<div id="showlink">
        <a href="#" id="submitBtnId" onclick="addDuctClickHandler();" data-icon="check" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-theme="b">Submit Final Test</a>
</div>
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: an alternative would be to use the require HTML5 attribute on which the form can't be submmitted until all required fields have been filled in

Comment: Jeroen is right, with the caution that HTML5 APIs are not available in all browswers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
// check for the change of any input in the form
$('#form_id :input').change(function(e) {

    // if any of the values are blank hide the link
    if ($('#form_id :input').map(function(idx, elem) {
            if ($(elem).val() === "") return $(elem);
        }).size() > 0)
        $("#showlink").hide();
    else
        $("#showlink").show();
});
```

The problem with your code is that it is attaching a change handler to the whole form instead of the inputs; I'm not even sure what affect this has.  Also you are using the `each` function to iterate over all the inputs in the entire document, not just the form, and the link will be shown and hidden for each one of them depending on their value so ultimately the link will be visible or hidden based solely on the last value inspected in the iteration.

Comment: I have set up a js fiddle with your example... Don't use it a whole lot so I think I have it set up as described. It isn't quite working. http://jsfiddle.net/swJAq/

Comment: @ChrisPilie I updated my answer, the selector was just a little off, it needed to be `$('#form_id :input')` instead of `$('form#form_id:input')`.  Also on your jsfiddle you need to add `style="display: none"` to the showlink div so that it is initially hidden.

Comment: thanks! I updated the fiddle. It does work there but still not in my code. I am not sure where my conflict is coming in. The same issue is happening with Kurt's answer.

Comment: What other scripts do you include in your code?  Is the Html structure any different?

Comment: All I have is http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.1.min.js up tom in the script tag. Not sure where my conflict is coming in.

Answer (score 3):

You are going over every field (with the `each` function). When the value is empty, you hide the link, but then you continue to run over the other fields. You should put a 'break' statement, when the value is empty, so that further processing stops. It would even be better to just go through all fields and maintain a boolean parameter. After the loop, you hide or show the link depending on the boolean parameter.

Like this:

```
$('#showlink').hide(); // Assume form is incomplete

$( 'form#form_id' ).change(function(e) {
 var complete = true; // Set start of boolean expression

 $(":input").each(function() {
    complete = complete && $(this).val() !== ""; //If val is empty, the whole expression  after the iteration will evaluate to false
 });

 if(complete) {
   $("#showlink").show();
 }
});
```

Comment: This one seems to work in fiddle but doesn't work on my code. I might have a conflict somewhere else... http://jsfiddle.net/SP8TC/

Comment: Could you give more info? Is there anything in your console log?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(this).val().indexOf(""))
```

or

```
if($(this).val.indexOf(""))
```

Try using `indexOf` to see if user has entered something

Answer (score 0):

Other variant in addition to @asymptoticFault's answer - use a variable to save if the link should be hidden or not:

```
$('form#form_id' ).change(function(e) {
  var should_hide = false;
  $(":input").each(function() {
    if($(this).val() === ""){
      should_hide = true;
      return false; // do not process each any more
    }
  });
  if (should_hide) {
    $("#showlink").hide();
  } else {
    $("#showlink").show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

well you could do this:

```
var $allInputs = $("input:text"),
    $button = $("#btnSubmit").hide();

$allInputs.change(function(){
    var isEmpty = $allInputs.filter(function(){
                  return ($(this).val()=="");
              });
    $button.hide();
    if(isEmpty.length == 0){
        $button.show();
    }
});
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/QwvtL/4/